# What constant can I use for the default Aqua space in Autolayout?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

According to the [Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/constraintFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH2-SW1), I can use a dash in the visual constraint format language to "denote the standard Aqua space:"

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[a]-[b]"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:viewDict]];
```

However, I can't seem to find an `NSLayout...` constant or method that allows me to do the same thing if I'm building a constraint *without* using the visual format language:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:a
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:b
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                multiplier:1.0f
                                                  constant:<# ??? #>]];
```

Is there a constant (or another value or method) that I can use to define the Aqua space in such a situation?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've found the "standard Aqua space" to be 8.0 between sibling views, and 20.0 between a view and its superview.

```
NSView* view = [NSView new] ;
NSLayoutConstraint* constraintWithStandardConstantBetweenSiblings = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[view]-[view]"  options:0  metrics:nil  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view) ] [0] ;
CGFloat standardConstantBetweenSiblings = constraintWithStandardConstantBetweenSiblings.constant ;    // 8.0

NSView* superview = [NSView new] ;
[superview addSubview:view] ;
NSLayoutConstraint* constraintWithStandardConstantBetweenSuperview = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[view]-|"  options:0  metrics:nil  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view) ] [0] ;
CGFloat standardConstantBetweenSuperview = constraintWithStandardConstantBetweenSuperview.constant ;    // 20.0
```

Comment: Excellent answer! This is the only solution to this I've found to date! Great!

Answer (score 10):

For iOS users:

```
#import "NSLayoutConstraint+StandardOffsets.h"

@implementation NSLayoutConstraint (StandardOffsets)

+ (CGFloat)standardConstantBetweenSiblings
{
    static CGFloat value;

    if(!isnormal(value)) {
        UIView *view = [UIView new] ;
        NSLayoutConstraint* constraintWithStandardConstantBetweenSiblings = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[view]-[view]"  options:0  metrics:nil  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view) ] [0] ;
        value = constraintWithStandardConstantBetweenSiblings.constant ;    // 8.0
    }
    return value;
}

+ (CGFloat)standardConstantBetweenSuperview
{
    static CGFloat value;

    if(!isnormal(value)) {
        UIView *view = [UIView new] ;
        UIView *superview = [UIView new] ;
        [superview addSubview:view] ;
        NSLayoutConstraint* constraintWithStandardConstantBetweenSuperview = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[view]-|"  options:0  metrics:nil  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view) ] [0] ;
        value = constraintWithStandardConstantBetweenSuperview.constant ;    // 20.0
    }
    return value;
}

@end
```

PS: I entered a bugreport that no constant is offered in the header files!

Comment: strangely the method `standardConstantBetweenSuperview` returns a value **0.0** sometimes instead of **20.0**. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @GoGreen In ios8? Things changed with it there are margins now - something like that.

Comment: I checked only in iOS8, but even though if margins are considered, the constant value should never be **0.0** right?

Answer (score 5):

Based on [John Sauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057523/104200), I wound up writing a couple methods on an NSLayoutConstraint category to find the constants:

- `+standardAquaSpaceConstraintFromItem:toItem:` returns a single NSLayoutConstraint constructed using the visual format language; it asserts that the array of constraints generated from the format has exactly one item, then gets that item and gives it back.
- `+standardAquaSpaceFromItem:toItem:` pulls the constant out of the constraint from the previous method and returns it as a CGFloat.

This way, I can either get the constant value myself if I need to do computations, or just get a single layout constraint with the right spacing (e.g. for assigning to a constraint `@property` or directly adding to my view).

Comment: Where are these methods? Can I use them?

Comment: @BenLeggiero: the actual implementation belongs to my employer, unfortunately, so I can't post it up here. However, the better solution nowadays is probably to use the anchor-based constraint methods; see NSLayoutAnchor (and on iOS, UILayoutGuide).