# Centering two buttons with Cocoa Auto Layout

Tags: ios6, autolayout

I have a problem with Cocoa Auto Layout and can't get my head around this problem.
All I'd like to achieve is to have two buttons always centered in a view as depicted below.

[image]

I've tried lots of different approaches without any success :( please help me out here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14741713/1523962

Comment: Oh my! That's so clever! But I guess for odd number of buttons the approach will be similar but slightly different, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another trick to do this is to align the right side of `button` to be half the size of the space away from the Center of `superview`, and the left side of `button2` to be half the size of the space away from the Center of `superview`.

This only really works if you have a superview that only surrounds the two views you want to centre though.

Answer (score 34):

I'm writing this from memory so hopefully all the information is right. I'm using XCode5. Here's the way I ended up doing this starting from no constraints:

1. Select both buttons and **add constraints to set their height and
   width** in the Add New Constraints window accessible from the second
   button on the bottom right of the IB canvas.
2. With both buttons still selected **add constraints to set their Y
   position**. Either the space above or space below in the Add New
   Constraints window will do.
3. Now select Button 1 and **add an alignment constraint "Horizontal
   Center In Container"** in the Add New Alignment Constraints window
   accessible from the first button the bottom right of the IB Canvas.
   By default the "constant" value of the added constraint is 0. We
   want to change that because it is wrong.
4. At this point button 1 will have a **yellow bar** running vertically
   through it. This is a warning indicating that the horizontal center
   of the button is not equal to the horizontal center of the container
   + the constraint's constant (0). The **number** on the vertical bar is how far off from center the button is. Remember that number.
5. Either double click the vertical yellow bar on Button 1 (dexterity
   required) or select button 1 go to the left pane and click on the
   ruler and "select and edit" the constraint called "Align Center X
   to:".
6. Input the **number from Step 4** in the **text box labeled "constant"**.
   Button 1 has now satisfied all the constraints it needs to for its
   display. It has a width, height, Y (top space or bottom space
   constraint), and now an X (horizontal center alignment). Button 2,
   however is still missing its X position which it can piggy back off
   Button 1.
7. **Select Button 2**, goto the Add New Constraints window and simply **set
   the leading space to Button 1** (the left bar off the top white box).

You should now have two buttons which will always stay in the center of their container at a fixed width apart from each other.

Comment: Amazing. That taught me a few things about autolayout, aside from actually fixing my problem that I had no idea how to approach. Thanks!

Comment: Also works with any amount of buttons. Not so obvious like "Flexible space" in UIBarButtonItem, but something...

Comment: Excellent, excellent answer. Works like a charm, and instructs on how to use constraints at the same time. Bravo.

Comment: Interesting hack. But I guess it won't work with dynamic element width ;)

Comment: This isn't working in Xcode 7.2 anymore. I posted what I did in my answer below. I'm using Swift, if that's in any way related.

Answer (score 10):

A neat trick with Auto Layout is to use invisible views as spacers. The constraint system still lays them out as normal. In this case, that space between the two buttons can be an invisible view. You can use the constraints from this constraint string:

```
@"[button][invisibleView(5)][button2(==button)]"
```

Then create a constraint setting `invisibleView.centerX = superview.centerX`.

Comment: Or you can put them both in a container view! Then center the container view.

Comment: This wouldn't work because you're assuming the two buttons are the same size.  Which *could* be, but may not be.

Comment: Despite this having twice the upvotes, I'd say jmathew's answer is the way to go. Centering one in super with a constant offset works flawlessly.

Comment: Matthew's answer didn't work for me. This did. I used an invisible view of width zero and did it all in IB

Answer (score 4):

If you have fixed width buttons and you want fixed distance between two then following steps can do the work :

1. add `Width` and `Height` `constraint` to `button1` Example value: 100 height and 100 width.
2. select both buttons and add `constraint` `Equal Widths` and `Equal Heights`.
3. add `Horizontal Spacing` between `button1` and `button2`. or we can say add `Leading Space` to `button2` from `button1`. Example value : 150
4. select `button1` and add `constraint` `Horizontally in Container` with -125 value.
5. add other `constrains` like `Vertical Spacing to Container` etc as per needed.

Example value 125 is equals to (`button1` `width` / 2) + (`Horizontal Spacing`/2) which is 100/2 + 150/2 = 125.

So adding `Horizontal in Container` to -125 will move the `buttons` to left and that will make this layout center in screen.

Example layout and Constraints images attached below :[image: Example Layout]

[image: Constraints on button1]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I have two `UIButtons` inside my `UITableViewCell` positioned below that needs to be always centered and with same widths. This is how I made it work in Xcode 7.2. I'm using Swift by the way, if that's in any way related.

1. In the left button, I gave it a **leading** and **bottom constraints**
2. In the right button, I gave it a **trailing** and **bottom constraints**
3. In the right button, I gave it a **leading space to the left button**
4. Lastly, in my right button, I gave it an **equal width constraints to the left button**.
5. Done.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieved as below way also.

1.Take Leading space for left button, Trailing space for right button.
2.Construct Outlets for both Leading and Trailing constraints.

```
 __weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leadingConstraint;
 __weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *trailingConstraint;
```

3.Caluclate constants as below formula.

```
NSInteger constant = (SCREEN_WIDTH - (CGRectGetWidth(leftButton.frame) + CGRectGetWidth(rightButton.frame))) / 3;
    leadingConstraint.constant = constant;
    trailingConstraint.constant = constant;
```

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Great tips.
In my case i wanted the buttons to be centered 10 pixels apart from the center of my view  so my math is slightly different

```
leadingConstraint.constant = (self.frame.size.width / 2.0) + 5.0;
trailingConstraint.constant = (self.frame.size.width / 2.0) + 5.0;
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is having to update constraints' constant manually on self.frame change.