# Change position with auto layout and constraints

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, constraints

I have a problem and I'm not sure whether you can solve it with auto layout and constraints or not.

**Problem:**
I have two objects on a view. 
If the orientation is in landscape mode the objects fit side by side. 
But on portrait mode parts of the second object are outside of the view. Therefore it should be placed under the first object instead side-by-side.

Can you realize this with auto layout and constraints?

Or

Do I have to change the position programmatically?

I uploaded two screenshots:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3502/f9us2a8x_png.htm
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3502/ddmurpwt_png.htm

thanks for any help!
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help as well https://github.com/yas375/ExampleApp/tree/39b921b373b14c928d073c0b2451bcfbf79682df

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20119117/2127824

Comment: nice thanks, this helped a lot. this tutorial was very useful, too:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it using auto layout.
I would check programmatically whether obj1.frame.size.width+obj2.frame.size.width > superview.bounds.size.width and set obj1 and obj2 frames accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use autolayout.

I think the problem is that you are centering the left object to the middle of the view and fixing the distance between the two of them.

You can check this stackoverflow question, it gives you 2 or 3 ways to do that: [Auto Layout (Constraints) Center 2 side by side views in a parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741713/auto-layout-constraints-center-2-side-by-side-views-in-a-parent-view)