# Stackview arrange issue

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uistackview

I have a **Horizontal StackView inside vertical StackView**.

Horizontal StackView contains a image (w=30 , h= 30) and a label.

[image: Current]

**Need**

I need to make image & label to center horizontally as per label intrinsic content size.

So, it looks like ----Space----- image & label -----Space---

**How can I achieve that?**

**Thank you,**

Comment: Did you check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741713/auto-layout-constraints-center-2-side-by-side-views-in-a-parent-view

Answer (score 1):

i am using only horizontal stackView to make it center.
What i did.

**Step 1:**

make my image with specific width and height.

**Step 2:**

Both are inserted in Horizontal stackView and make that stackView center aligned.

[image]

[image]

**Edited:**

If i use vertical stack View On top, i can't find any problem for centering label and image
[image]

[image]

Comment: but my  Horizontal StackView inside vertical StackView.

Comment: @nirav:- you can check my another answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can use UIView inside Horizontal StackView then add image and label on UIView

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it will also not work as view's width is equal to the stackview. I already tried this.

Comment: please take a look on attached image

Comment: but my  Horizontal StackView is inside vertical StackView.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on attached image

[image]

Comment: my vertical view has leading,traling,top,bottom = 0, so this will not work for me

Comment: @nirav:- please check new image

Comment: @nirav: I just edited my answer. Feel free to reply if you face any problem.

Comment: view can't be same width & height as stack view.

Answer (score 0):

Because the VerticalStackView forces the HorizontalStackView to have same width, So you have to wrap imageView and label inside a UIView. Like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add two extra views, I named it View 1 and View 2(green color) on left and right of your image and label, set two views width equal so your imageView and label will automatically center, don't forget set width for imageView and label. Set view 1 and view 2 clear color or under other view view if needed(to see background, other views, interaction with other views...).