# NSAutoLayout standard space value

Tags: ios, autolayout

When using AutoLayout you can tick the "standard" box in Interface Builder or you can create it visually using... @"|-[someElement]-|"

Is there a constant that I can use to access the value that this "standard" represents?

I want to create an `NSLayoutConstraint` where the `constant` property is equal to this `standard` value.

Comment: It would be good to have constants defined for all the "standard" values available in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057523/693322) to [What constant can I use for the default Aqua space in Autolayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055900/what-constant-can-i-use-for-the-default-aqua-space-in-autolayout), the standard Aqua space is

> **8.0** between sibling views, and **20.0** between a view and its superview.

There are no predefined constants so you'd have to define your own.