# How can you get in code the value of standard spacing used in autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, autolayout

I was wondering if there is a way to find the values that correspond with Standard when you set autolayout separation in XCode.

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There does not appear to be a constant available that you can access. Based on [What constant can I use for the default Aqua space in Autolayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055900/what-constant-can-i-use-for-the-default-aqua-space-in-autolayout/14057523#14057523) the spacings are:

- 20.0 between parent and child views (eg. a child view will start at 20, 20)
- 8.0 between sibling views (eg. two children of the same parent will be 8.0 units apart)